# Will async come back one day?

Tags: rebol

I don't understand why async as described here
http://www.rebol.com/article/0050.html

is no more available in lastest releases. Will it return back any time soon or has the name changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google for async-protocol.r

Comment: thank you. Is it the same as the original ? Why was it removed in that case ?

Comment: It was removed as it was unstable.  The 3rd party async protocols are stable though.  

Of course Rebol3 uses all async protocols.

Looks like you asked this before too .. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653969/rebol-multitasking-with-async-why-do-i-get-invalid-port-spec